# Is there a function in qiskit that allows me to insert quantum gates at certain indices of a circuit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

Here's my quantum circuit with mid-circuit measurements:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(1, 'c')
base_circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
for i in range(N):
    base_circ.measure(0,0)
    base_circ.barrier()
base_circ.draw()
```

[image]

I wonder is there a method in qiskit that allows me to insert quantum gates at certain indices? For example, in this case, can I add another instruction to add two `x` gates before the first two measurements (one for each)? I found [this post](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4736#issuecomment-663993070) might be helpful, but I'm not able to implement instructions like `qc.h(anc[0],i=6)` or `circuit.gate(qubit).at(index)` in my case as it returns errors. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If you read till the end of the issue you linked in the description: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4736, you will see that this feature is currently is not supported in Qiskit and won't be introduced unless there is a strong use case for such actions: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4736#issuecomment-704411394

Comment: @Junye Huang Thank you!

Comment: @ZR- this is currently supported with `circuit.data.insert`

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

In Qiskit 0.37, the internal data structure of the `QuantumCircuit.data` attribute has been refactored. Instead of a list of tuples, it becomes a list of [`CircuitInstruction`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.CircuitInstruction.html) objects.

Code has been updated to reflect this change.

---

From my experience, most of the time you can restructure your code to avoid the need for inserting gates in the middle of a circuit.

That said, if you already know the insertion points at the time of circuit creation but you don't know the gates to be inserted, you can add *placeholders* at these places and replace them later with whatever gates you want.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Instruction
from qiskit.circuit import CircuitInstruction
from typing import Union

class Placeholder(Instruction):
    def __init__(self, num_qubits, label):
        self.name = "placeholder"
        super().__init__(self.name, num_qubits, 0, [], label = label)

    def inverse(self):
        return Placeholder(self.name, self.num_qubits)

# This function accepts a QuantumCircuit in addition to single instructions
# Note: you can modify it to accept a dictionary of label-instruction pairs.
def replace(self, placeholder_label, instruction: Union[Instruction, QuantumCircuit]):
    if isinstance(instruction, QuantumCircuit):
        instruction = instruction.to_instruction()

    self._data = [CircuitInstruction(instruction, _inst[1], _inst[2]) if _inst[0].name == 'placeholder' and _inst[0].label == placeholder_label else _inst for _inst in self._data]

QuantumCircuit.replace = replace
```

As an example, let's create a new circuit with some placeholders

```
circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.h(0)
circ.x(1)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.append(Placeholder(2, 'First'), [0, 1])
circ.cx(1, 0)
circ.append(Placeholder(1, 'Second'), [0])
circ.measure_all()
circ.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Now, let's replace these placeholders with actual gates:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import HGate, SwapGate

circ.replace('First', SwapGate())
circ.replace('Second', HGate())
circ.draw('mpl')
```

The final circuit should look like
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The code returns `NameError: name 'Instruction' is not defined`. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I updated my answer so that the code snippets include all the needed imports

Comment: Thanks for the update, I still get a ​`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`. When I delete the label, it shows the circuit but all labels are 'Placeholder'.

Comment: What version do you have for qiskit? Instruction didn't support labels before version 0.28

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to apply this code to a circuit belonging a list created by a tomography list, but I get the error `QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'condition'`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Daniele Cuomo, could you share your code?

Comment: I tried to replace the ReplaceHolder with a QuantumCircuit object rather than a Gate one.

Comment: I meant by my note that the function can be modified to accept `QuantumCircuit`s . I updated the function definition.  Now, it *does* accept `QuantumCircuit`s  in addition to `Instruction`s. You can give it a try and tell me if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the revision! Actually, yes: the Union package is missing.

Comment: Add `from typing import Union`. Or just remove type check. That is, remove `: Union[Instruction, QuantumCircuit]`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **no, there is no way to insert gates in a middle of a circuit**.

As [explained](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23589/is-there-a-function-in-qiskit-that-allows-me-to-insert-quantum-gates-at-certain#comment30939_23589), the issue https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/4736 has a longer explanation on why not.

The mid size explanation is the following: generally speaking, a circuit is not a *sequence* of instructions and, therefore, there is no *indices* to insert things in. A circuit is more like a directed acyclic graph where the gates are nodes and the edges are dependency relation on qubits. It is very hard to define an API that is simple but expressive enough to refer to an unambiguous position in it.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is `circuit.data.insert`. Some simple examples  are detailed in [this paper](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/1903.04359.pdf). For your example, we have:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit

qr = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(1, 'c')
base_circ = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
for i in range(3):
    base_circ.measure(0,0)
    base_circ.barrier()
base_circ.draw()

Output:
     ┌─┐ ░ ┌─┐ ░ ┌─┐ ░ 
  q: ┤M├─░─┤M├─░─┤M├─░─
     └╥┘ ░ └╥┘ ░ └╥┘ ░ 
c: 1/═╩═════╩═════╩════
      0     0     0
```

Note that as mentioned in another answer, this circuit is just a list of `CircuitInstruction` types

```
print(base_circ.data)

Output:
[CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='x', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=()), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='measure', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=1, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=(Clbit(ClassicalRegister(1, 'c'), 0),)), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='barrier', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=()), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='x', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=()), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='measure', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=1, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=(Clbit(ClassicalRegister(1, 'c'), 0),)), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='barrier', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=()), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='measure', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=1, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=(Clbit(ClassicalRegister(1, 'c'), 0),)), CircuitInstruction(operation=Instruction(name='barrier', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qubits=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(1, 'q'), 0),), clbits=())]
```

And so inserting operations is just a matter of inserting `CircuitInstruction` objects to this list. Now there might be a better way to do this, but if I wanted to insert an X gate before the first two measures, I'd first declare a circuit that is just an X gate, and then insert that as a `CircuitInstruction` with the built-in methods.

```
x_gate = QuantumCircuit(1)
x_gate.x(0)
base_circ.data.insert(0, x_gate.data[0])
base_circ.data.insert(3, x_gate.data[0])
base_circ.draw()

Output:
     ┌───┐┌─┐ ░ ┌───┐┌─┐ ░ ┌─┐ ░ 
  q: ┤ X ├┤M├─░─┤ X ├┤M├─░─┤M├─░─
     └───┘└╥┘ ░ └───┘└╥┘ ░ └╥┘ ░ 
c: 1/══════╩══════════╩═════╩════
           0          0     0
```

Note that after the first insertion, your indices change. So as long as you keep tabs of where you are trying to insert operations you should be fine. Also note that the `qubits` field in `CircuitInstruction` need to match with the circuit you're trying to insert. Meaning that if you do it the way I showed here, the `QuantumCircuit` for the single X gate needs to be of the same register size.